# Работа с YouTube API Python

Tags: python, youtube-api

Час добрый
Сможет кто-нибудь подсказать, как при помощи api youtube, который работает через панель разработчика в google, достать описание профиля канала? Всё то, что находится на странице about. Т. е., описание и ссылки.
Разобрался с работой для видео на канале, а вот с профилем что-то не могу разобраться. Буду рад помощи, заранее благодарю.

Comment: вот эта штука не подойдёт ? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels  snippet.description вроде то что вы ищите